# Can I use a list to address a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to assign a value to an element of a numpy array addressed by a list. Is this possible? It seems like the sort of thing you ought to be able to do.

I tried:

```
q = np.zeros((2,2,2))
index = [0,0,0]
print(index)


q[index]=4.3
print(q)
```

Which didn't give an error, which is promising, but q is now:

```
[[[ 4.3  4.3]
  [ 4.3  4.3]]

 [[ 0.   0. ]
  [ 0.   0. ]]]
```

As opposed to:

```
[[[ 4.3  0. ]
  [ 0.   0.]]

 [[ 0.   0. ]
  [ 0.   0. ]]]
```

As I hoped it would be.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a `list` to index a single element - it has to be a `tuple`:

```
import numpy as np

q = np.zeros((2,2,2))
index = [0,0,0]
print(index)


q[tuple(index)]=4.3
print(q)
[0, 0, 0]
[[[ 4.3  0. ]
  [ 0.   0. ]]

 [[ 0.   0. ]
  [ 0.   0. ]]]
```

Comment: Technically, you can use a list. ``q[[0,0,0]] = 4.3`` is equivalent to ``q[0] = 4.3; q[0] = 4.3; q[0] = 4.3``.

Comment: @fjarri that's indeed true... matter of taste I s'pose

Comment: I wouldn't call it a matter of taste, it's a different operation that gives a different result. Just saying that you can use a list.